# Debug function simply won't print to console

Tags: lua, computercraft

I made a debug function that only outputs if the program is running in debug mode, but for some reason it simply won't work.

```
function debug{...}
  if bDebug then --bDebug is whether the program is in debug mode. It's set to true.
    for i,v in ipairs(arg) do
      print("[DEBUG] "..v)
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the program's output:

```
fireflyGLASS v0.1 alpha
Initializing classes...
1/5 Initialized 'box'
...
5/5 Initialized 'playerSurface'
```

I have a line of code that says `debug("Running in debug mode.")` but nowhere in there does it say that.

Can someone please tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Wait! I figured it out.

Turns out that I initialized `local bDebug` after I initialized `debug()`, which made lua mad.